# Android: Use different drawables after choosing a different theme, keeping the same references

Tags: android, layout, themes

Is possible to make the app use different drawables after choosing a theme in Android?

**An explanatory example:**

i have a layout which background uses a reference to: "@drawable/backgroundsolid", that is image backgroundsolid.png in **res/drawable-mdpi**.

I want that, if the user choose "Glass" theme, the reference stays to "@drawable/backgroundsolid" but the resources folder is changed to **res/drawable-glass**, which contains a different backgroundsolid.png image.

Is it possible to set this programmatically? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programmatically by using `view.setBackgroundResourceId()`. I am not sure if you do it the other way which is let android pick the right theme for you. Maybe someone else has a better answer

Comment: Thanks Amir, but I need to apply the theme globally, including icons and images, not only backgrounds. I already know how to set different images using resources, I want to know if it is possible to choose different resources folders programmatically.